# how to put 4 thumbnails on a sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a sidebar which is col-md-2. now I need to put 4 thumbnail next to each other on this sidebar that picture of them would be responsive. whith this code image become bigger when I resize the window (make window smaller)

```
    <div class=col-md-2>
   <div class=row>

   <div class=col-md-3>
   <div class="thumbnail>
   <a href="#">
   <img srcset="address" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="caption">
   a
   </div>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>

  <div class=col-md-3>
   <div class="thumbnail>
   <a href="#">
   <img srcset="address" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="caption">
  a
   </div>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class=col-md-3>
   <div class="thumbnail>
   <a href="#">
   <img srcset="address" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="caption">
  a
   </div>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class=col-md-3>
   <div class="thumbnail>
   <a href="#">
   <img srcset="address" class="img-responsive">
   <div class="caption">
   a
   </div>
   </a>
   </div>
   </div>

  <div><!--end of row>
  <div>
```

[image: image of what I need]

Comment: Please provide examples of what you mean, is there a website or a picture that can demonstrate this? It's not obvious what you are looking for in the question.

Comment: There is some missing quotes in your code and you have also forgotten to put `class` in the first div. Here is a jsfiddle with the code i think you are trying to show: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33116/

Comment: @JacobPålsson I add a picture like something that I need. actually I need 4 thumbnail in a row that would be responsive. my code create 4 thumbnail in a line in the sidebar but my problem is its image size change when I resize window

Comment: Do you want the images to be a fixed size? Do you want the sidebar to be a fixed size or should that be responsive? Please edit your question to make it more clear so that more people can help.